# Add a list inside a bigger List

Tags: python, list

````
```python
whole_list = []
x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6]
```
````

Expected output: 
whole_List = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

I tried using whole_list.extend(x,y) but it it said that it can only take one argument.
Is there an effective way to add list of x,y into the list of whole_list?

Comment: `whole_list.append(x)`

Comment: What language? [tag:python]? How specifically did you try using `extend` and what exactly does *"doesn't work"* mean? [Edit] to tag the appropriate language and give a [mre].

Comment: `whole_list = [x, y]`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a list containing both list *x* and *y*, you can just do:

```
whole_list = []
x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6]

whole_list.append(x)
whole_list.append(y)
```

You can also redefine `whole_list`:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6]

whole_list = [x,y]
```

Both will produce the same list `whole_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`

---

Additionaly, if you want to **extend** the list by lists *x* and *y*, you can do this:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6]

whole_list = x + y
```

This will give you `whole_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` - a list containing **the elements** of lists *x* and *y*